# What is an efficient way for logging in an existing system

Tags: exception, business-intelligence, business-logic

I have the following in my system:

- 4 File folders
- 5 Applications that do some processing on files in the folders and then move files to the next folder (processing: read files, update db..)

The process is defined by Stages: 1,2,3,4,5.
As the files are moved along, the Stage field within them is updated to the next Stage.

Sometimes there are exceptions in the system, not necessarily exception in code but exception in the process.
For instance, there is an error in transmitting the file to the next folder. In this case the stage is not updated and an record is written in the DB for this file.

**What I want to do, what is the best approach?**

I want to plug a utility of some sort or add code to the applications that will capture any exceptions in the process. Like if a file was not moved, I want to know what stage and why. This will help in figuring out the break down in the process.
I need something that will provide the overall health of the process.
Now sure how to go about doing this from an architectural point of view.

Comment: If by application you mean an exe. Then one way would be to set an exit code and have whatever launched it act on it.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson yes I mean exe by application. Could you elaborate on 'exit code'? The app gets called by the scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

The scheduler? Well that might knock the idea out anyway.

Exit code is still up and running from dos days.

it's a property of the Application Class (0 the default) is success

So from your app you'd detect an error and set `ApplicationExitCode` to some meaning number like 1703 (boo hoo)

```
Application.ShutDown(1703);// is the .net4 way
```

However seeing as presumably the scheduler is just running the app, you'd have to script it all up. Might as well just write a common logging dll and add it to each app as mess about with that, especially if you want the same behaviour if it's run from outside the scheduler.

Another option would be delegating. ie you write an app that runs the app (passed in as a command line parameter) and logs the result (via exit code for instance) and then change  scheduler items to call that with the requisite parameter.